# How to use socket.io with engine.io as a transport?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm looking to use features of socket.io, such as custom events, rooms, and broadcasting, but I want to use engine.io as a transport layer for of its more-reliable upgrade-based rather than fallback-based design.

I feel like that's possible after reading [this article](http://www.devthought.com/2012/07/07/the-realtime-engine/#more-1658):

> **Engine.IO acts as a transport layer** for the data exchanged by Socket.IO between a server and a browser. **It does not replace Socket.IO**. It simply abstracts out the inherent complexity of supporting realtime data exchange in multiple browsers, devices and networks.

Does anyone know if that is possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

engine.io IS the transport layer of socket.io. You don't have to do anything.
Look at this package.json file to see the dependency: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/package.json